# How can i retrieve server name from a UNC path which leads to a DFS file

Tags: perl, powershell, cmd, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a DFS UNC path `\\rootxx\xx\xx\` which leads to a file in a remote server ,how can i retrieve the server name , where the file resides  using perl.

Comment: [`NetDfsGetInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb524812.aspx)? `NetDfsGetInfo` seems to have been made available by [Win32::Lanman](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Lanman).

Comment: @ikegami : NetDfsGetInfo cmdlet is not recognized and can't download it as well , is it by default working in your powershell or did you install it from some repository

Comment: @LotPings : no it is not a duplicate , DFS stands for distributed file system  and `rootxx` is not the server name , the path leads to a file which is another server

Comment: @LotPings : did you down vote ?if you did read the question carefully and study whats DFS

Comment: cmdlet? I linked to a system call and a Perl module

Answer (score 1):

Only a minute of gooogling gives [some links](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c2946146-2580-450a-8f41-65f4b8cbf5dd/get-dfs-targets-in-powershell-v2?forum=winserverpowershell)

```
dfsutil link <dfsfolder>
```

If you by any chance have the option to use powershell v3+ you can use

```
Get-DfsnFoldertarget <dfs folder> | select targetpath
```

If you want a list of Shares that are linked to a DFS path then try:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DFSTarget|
  Where {$_.LinkName -like "\\Domain\DFS\Folder"}|
    Select @{n='Path';e={"\\{0}\{1}" -f $_.ServerName,$_.ShareName}}
```

Comment: I tried all those commands  and they were not recognized as internal or external command , so i posted the question with just two tags perl and cmd and then you asked me to include powershell , and ok how can i execute this command , i don't think it is possible to download cmdlets

Comment: If you have access to a distributed file system, you should also have access to one of your administrators who can provide details of the dfs utils/cmdlets.

Comment: Soon that doesn't matter any more, I already removed the comment but there are 3 other close votes for your question.

Comment: Seriously? I think it's lack of information first hand and your ahem childish behavior getting you such a response. Are you burning your 11 days old profile intentionally?